# ms sql convert string to date changing the order from yyyy-mm-dd to dd.mm.yyyy

Tags: sql

I have a field named `VALUE` of `VARCHAR2` type

The string is in this format: `yyyy-mm-dd`
Is it possible to change it to: `dd-mm-yyyy`

An then (again if possible) to convert it to date in this format?

What I have tried is:

```
SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 110)
```

but it's only for the current time. Is there a way to do this?

Edit:
Here my code is:

```
select
p1.VALUE as Sdate
from Process p 
LEFT JOIN PARAMETER p1 on p1.WP_ID=p.ID AND p1.NAME = 'Sdate'
WHERE p.TYPE = 'Marketing' and convert(varchar, convert(date,p1.value), 103) ='22.08.2012'
```

Comment: You should be storing dates in a `DATETIME` or `DATE` column, not a `VARCHAR2` column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`104` will convert in `dd.mm.yyyy` format

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 104)
```

Your query should be:

```
SELECT p1.VALUE AS Sdate
FROM Process p 
LEFT JOIN PARAMETER p1 
       ON p1.WP_ID = p.ID 
      AND p1.NAME = 'Sdate'
WHERE p.TYPE = 'Marketing' 
  AND CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(DATE, p1.value), 104) = '22.08.2012'
```

#### See an example in [this SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b685e/22).

Note that you should keep the column type as `DATE` where you want to store dates. Also, always prefer `yyyyMMdd` format.

Have a look at [CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

Comment: it says: "Type DATE is not a defined system type."

Answer (score 2):

```
        SELECT convert(varchar, columnname, 103) from tablename
        or
        SELECT convert(varchar, convert(date,'2012/11/01'), 103)
        or
       SELECT convert(varchar, convert(date,columnname), 103) from tablename
=================================
select
p1.VALUE as Sdate
from Process p 
LEFT JOIN PARAMETER p1 on p1.WP_ID=p.ID AND p1.NAME = 'Sdate'
WHERE p.TYPE = 'Marketing' and convert(varchar, convert(date,p1.value), 103) ='22/08/2012'
```

Comment: I just ran : convert(datetime,p11.value,103)= '22-08-2012' and got this error "The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value.
(1,047 sec)
"

Comment: But, you have date in varchar , so first convert date then assign date function

Comment: have you try this :SELECT convert(varchar, convert(date,columnname), 103) from tablename